# Averageing numbers in a column while ignoring rows with headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you average the numbers in a column and ignore those rows with text, or zero or null?

Comment: Can you explain better? Are you talking about averaging a single column and ignoring the text, zeros and null in that column? Or are you referring to adjacent cells which are text, zero or null?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will average the values in the range `B1:B5` whose corresponding cells in `A1:A5` are empty.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A5, "=", B1:B5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVERAGEIF` function. An example is:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A9,"<>0")
```

Replace `A1:A9` with the range that you want to average. The expression `"<>0"` will exclude any cells that have a zero value. Cells with text values and empty cells are ignored anyway.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the question is asking how to average cells based on whether a separate column is empty, based on the title which says "while ignoring rows with headers".

Comment: Yes, the question isn't very clear. However, I thought @Jack83 might mean that the headers are the text that he wants to exclude, along with the zeros and null values.

Comment: You might be right. We'll let Jack83 tell us which one he meant.